# How to hide file extension in website?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, file-extension

I want to hide the file extension on my website.
This is the content of my `.htaccess`:

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
```

For example:

`http://example.com/website2` will map to `http://example.com/website2.html`

Answer (score 0):

Make website2 a folder and put your html named as index.html in it.

Comment: This method would work, but is definitely not the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `http://example.com/website2` won't map to anything because there is no trailing slash. Your rule's regex is `^([^/]+)/$`, needs a trailing slash.

So you need to change **all of your links** from `http://example.com/website2.html` to `http://example.com/website2/`.

In order to redirect links you don't have any control over, you can add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /(.*)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```